# AttributeError: ‘Dataset’ object has no attribute ‘remove_columns’ in hugging face

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I want to remove column from Dataset Billsum from hugging face.
Error:
AttributeError: ‘Dataset’ object has no attribute ‘remove_columns’

I can't find any solution for this problem.. I have a headache from it
If someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this line to solve it

```
df= df.remove_columns([“column_name”])
```